# How to get file from ftp and store in odoo database

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, odoo-13

I want to download file from ftp server and store in binary field.
How can I do that?
Actually, I want to create the model and add the binary field for storing download file and read this file.

```html
class tog_sale(models.Model):
    _name = 'tog_sale.tog_sale'
    logging.info("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz")
    datas=fields.Many2many('ir.attachment')
    name=fields.Char(string="name")

    @api.model
    def schedule_download(self):
        attachment_obj = self.env['ir.attachment']
        with request.urlopen('ftp://localhost/Downloads/iris.csv') as response:
            attachment_obj.create({'name': 'iris.csv', 'datas': response.read()})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [urllib.request.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) to get a file from an FTP server, then use the read method to get `bytes` which will be used as a value for the binary field.

The following example store the downloaded file in `datas` binary field in `ir.attachment` table:

```
attachment_obj = self.env['ir.attachment']
with request.urlopen('ftp://ftp.dlink.eu/Manuals/DES-1008PA_Manual.pdf') as response:
    attachment_obj.create({'name': 'DES-1008PA_Manual.pdf', 'datas': response.read()})
```

***Edit:***

The [Binary](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#advanced-fields) field has an attribute `attachment` to specify whether the field should be stored as `ir_attachment` or in a column of the model’s table (`default: True`)

As I can see you added a many2many field to link records to `tog_sale`.

**Example:**

You can add one line to create an attachment and fill `datas` field:

```
with request.urlopen('ftp://ftp.dlink.eu/Manuals/DES-1008PA_Manual.pdf') as response:
    self.write({'datas': [(0, 0, {'name': 'DES-1008PA_Manual.pdf', 'datas': response.read()})]})
```

Comment: check my code .I edited in my post.It does not store in ir.attachment table.How can i do?Actually I want to store my file in tog_sale_to_sale table.

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: Not getting data in ir_attachment database

Comment: The downloaded file should be visible in datas field, just check `ir.attachment` for newly created record.